# Error CS1061 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseMySql'

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, asp.net-core-2.0

I just learn to use ASP.NET CORE 2.0 MVC using Visual Studio Community Edition.
I want to use MySQL database instead of using SQL Server because I need to use some data inside the old MySQL DB. Please help me solving this problem .. thank you

Here is my error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061  'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition
> for 'UseMySql' and no extension method 'UseMySql' accepting a first
> argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   LearnEFCore d:\temp\aspnet\LearnEFCore\LearnEFCore\Startup.cs   29  Active

My code as follow:

In [Startup.cs](https://pastebin.com/dzx8Hf8Q)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using LearnEFCore.Data;

....
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var sqlConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataAccessMySqlProvider");
            services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options => options.UseMySql(sqlConnectionString));
            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

In my appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DataAccessMySqlProvider": "server=localhost;port=3306;userid=root;password=root;database=sportstore;"
  }
}
```

In my Models/Data

```
using LearnEFCore.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace LearnEFCore.Data
{
    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>().ToTable("Enrollment");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Student");
        }
    }
}
```

My csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.10.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

changin to Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql solved the problem ...